# PHP/MySQL total by member

Tags: php, mysql

Like this a result :

```
75  Ansari  5   10      
88  Koodoo  4   0       
90  Koodoo  14  0       
83  Koodoo  5   0       
82  Koodoo, 6   0       
81  Koodoo  4   0       
79  Koodoo  5   0       
74  Savage  1   0       
80  Strike  2   36      
87  Strike  4   15      
78  Sullivan 3  15      
77  Sullivan 2  0
```

I would like to get the total for each member for the last 2 columns (Hours and Minutes).

My query look like that :

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    $tbl_name
ORDER BY
    player
```

If someone would have a quick fix for that I would appreciate it.

Comment: You want [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) (over the person) and then an aggregate like [SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) (over the columns to total) - I would recommend turning the hours/minutes into just minutes and returning a single value. Now go read :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you want something like this (but you didn't provide a schema so I'm guessing on the field names).

```
SELECT `id`, `player`, SUM(`hours`) as hours, SUM(`minutes`) as minutes FROM `$tbl_name` GROUP_BY `player`;
```

Comment: I did that : $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,player, SUM(hours), SUM(minutes) FROM members GROUP BY player");

It work on PHPMyAdmin but when i try to put it in PHP I get that error : mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in /hermes/bosweb/web161/b1615/ipg.jmdev/nmc/admin/totalTimes.php on line 70 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314419/php-mysql-total-by-member#

Line 70 : while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

Comment: You can't mix `msqli_query` with `mysql_fetch_array`. See http://php.net/mysqli_query -- `mysqli_query` returns a  `mysqli_result`. Probably what you want is `mysqli_fetch_array` (See http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_array).

Answer (score 0):

You need to [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) the user's name and [SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) the totals for the `hours` and `minutes` columns.

A Simple example of this is:

```
SELECT `id`, 
`user`, 
SUM(`hours`) as tot_hours, 
SUM(`mins`) as tot_mins 
FROM `test` 
GROUP BY `user`;
```

You can see this example run at this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5365f/4/0)

Note: With that fiddle, I removed the extra comma in this line (I assumed it was a typo)

```
82  Koodoo, 6   0
```

If that comma is supposed to be there, you just need to adjust that one insert statement to add the comma within the quotes of the name. That will adjust your query outcome as `Koodoo,` won't group with the other `Koodoo` values.